# How to display an NSArray in a label in a storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, nsarray, label, viewcontroller

I'm really new to programming and having a lot of trouble figuring out how to work with xcode. Im trying to connect an NSArray (which contains various questions and will display those questions in a random order) into a label I have on one of my ViewControllers in a storyboard. I've searched and tried and cant seem to get it. Can anyone help me figure it out? I feel like its really easy I'm just missing something.

Comment: Do you want to show the text for only one of those array items, or all of them?  If you want it to display one randomly, you probably want to set the label's text at runtime, rather than by making a connection in Xcode.  You could bind it to an array controller, but that will probably feel more complicated than just setting the text in response to whatever events should trigger it.

Comment: No I need all of them. What I am trying to do is have one of the questions from the list chosen and displayed in the label so that when the user moves onto the next question another question is randomly selected from the list and displayed. Basically I need it so that the order is not preselected but random (aka NSArray that is randomized) and is linked to a button that will display this. Also thank you for taking the time to respond :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. Here's what you do:

**1) Declare things…**

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *questionArray;
    UILabel *questionLabel;
}

@end
```

**2) ViewDidLoad:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //create question array
    questionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Question 1?", @"Question 2?", @"Question 3?", @"Question 4?", nil];

    //random a question
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = [questionArray count] - 1;
    int randomValue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);

    //create UILabel
    questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
    [questionLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [questionLabel setText:[questionArray objectAtIndex:randomValue]];
    [self.view addSubview:questionLabel];

    //create next button
    nextButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 100)];
    [nextButton setTitle:@"Next Question" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextQuestionButtonSelected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

**3) When button clicked..**

```
//Create action connection in the storyboard..
- (IBAction)nextQuestionButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    //random a question again
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = [questionArray count] - 1;
    int randomValue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);

    [questionLabel setText:[questionArray objectAtIndex:randomValue]];
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Just one thing :( Everything works except for the button I get one error. In the line "[nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextQuestionButtonSelected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];" in the implementation section I get an error "undeclared sector "nextQuestionButtonSelected" ".

Comment: @Matt Its just a warning, NO BIGGY! Remove that line. I forgot about it and it doesn't do anything. The method that does the work is `nextQuestionButtonClicked`

Comment: oh I realized I connected the button to the wrong IBAction! My bad. Anyways thank you its working fine now :D

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @Ty_ but is there any way I can make it so that this label is specific to only one storyboard and does not show up on multiple ones? (Just the label bc i changed it so that I have multiple storyboards so that when I click next question it just goes to the next storyboard which has the same label that picks a question randomly from questionArray. Basically my problem is the label is still showing up on storyboards that dont need the label like "Choose Difficulty" for example

Comment: @Matt I'd like to help Mat. But I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish… Can you please post another question, and ask clearly what you want. With screen shots of `storyboards` and `code` please. And I will try my best to answer your question.

Comment: I have posted another question, this time much more detailed and is hopefully easier to understand. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251358/how-to-specify-a-label-to-one-specific-storyboard